# Constructor error when injecting using Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, unity-container

Why I get this error **"The type MVCApplication1.HomeController does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (IRepository_1, IRepository_2)"** using Unity?

```
Public Class HomeController
Inherits Controller
Private _repo1 As IRepository_1
Private _repo2 As IRepository_2

Private Sub New(_repo1 As IRepository_1, _repo2 As IRepository_2)
    Me._repo1 = _repo1
    Me._repo2 = _repo2
End Sub

Function Index() As ActionResult

    Return View()
End Function
End Class
```

Bootstrapper

```
container.RegisterType(Of HomeController)(New InjectionConstructor(New ResolvedParameter(Of IRepository_1), New ResolvedParameter(Of IRepository_2)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor needs to be public

```
Public Sub New(_repo1 As IRepository_1, _repo2 As IRepository_2)
    Me._repo1 = _repo1
    Me._repo2 = _repo2
End Sub
```